# Relating properties of geometric morphisms to the inverse image of the generic model

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, topos-theory

Let $p:X\to [\mathbb{T}]$ be a morphism of Grothendieck topoi such that $[\mathbb{T}]$ is the classifying topos for some geometric theory $\mathbb{T}$; let me write $U$ for the generic model of $\mathbb{T}$ in $\mathbf{Sh}([\mathbb{T}]) = \mathbf{Set}[\mathbb{T}]$. I want to think about two different ways of looking at $p$:

1. (Classifying topos perspective):  We can think of $p$ as a $\mathbb{T}$-algebra $p^*U$ internal to category $\mathbf{Sh}(X)$.
2. (Giraud theorem perspective): We can think of $p$ as presenting $X$ by a site internal to the category $\mathbf{Set}[\mathbb{T}]$.

I would like to relate these two perspectives by having some kind of rosetta stone between properties of the $\mathbb{T}$-algebra $p^*U$ and properties of a site presentation for $p : X \to [\mathbb{T}]$ in $\mathbf{Set}[\mathbb{T}]$. My first question, for instance, is:

> Are there necessary and sufficient properties of the $\mathbb{T}$-algebra $p^*U$ for $p : X\to [\mathbb{T}]$ to be presentable by a site in $\mathbf{Set}[\mathbb{T}]$ with no Grothendieck topology, i.e. exhibiting $X$ as $\mathbf{Set}[\mathbb{T}]$-valued presheaves on an internal category $\mathbb{C}\in\mathbf{Set}[\mathbb{T}]$?

Does anyone know how to tackle such questions? Feel free to strengthen assumptions as-needed.

Comment: Have you considered the case where $\mathbb{T}$ is the initial geometric theory, so that the classifying topos is the terminal Grothendieck topos? There is a unique model of $\mathbb{T}$ in any Grothendieck topos, so it is hard to imagine what properties of it would tell you whether the topos is a presheaf topos or not.

Comment: @ZhenLin That's a great point...

Comment: As you've stated them, I think (1) and (2) have different implicit presuppositions.  To talk about (1), you have to be given the topos $X$ to start with, whereas this isn't the case with (2).  For an apples-to-apples comparison, (1) would have to be "a topos $X$ together with an internal $\mathbb{T}$-algebra", to go along with (2) "A site internal to $\mathbf{Set}[\mathbb{T}]$".  Thus, properties of an internal site in $\mathbf{Set}[\mathbb{T}]$ would have to be compared to properties of "a topos $X$ together with an internal $\mathbb{T}$-algebra".

Comment: So, for your specific question, we should be looking for properties of $X$ *together with* the $\mathbb{T}$-algebra $p^*U$ that would ensure $p$ is a presheaf topos over $\mathbf{Set}[\mathbb{T}]$.  This explains @ZhenLin's example: when $\mathbb{T}$ is empty, the property of the pair $(X,p^*U)$ is just that "$X$ is a presheaf topos" since there is nothing nontrivial that can be said about $p^*U$.